# Objective C JAVA endian

Tags: java, objective-c, endianness

I'm using a 64 bit Mac, and I'm sure that Java (1.6 in my case) is using big-endians.

I'm trying to communicate to my java server from my iPhone in Objective C.  Is the iPhone(objective C) using little or big endian?

If it's using little endian, how do I convert the NSData *size into bigEndian so Java can read it correctly?

```
int s = [protoToSend serializedSize]; 
NSData *size = [NSData dataWithBytes:&s length:1];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can change the Java side to use little endian. DataInputStream only supports Big Endian, but ByteBuffer supports either.

Comment: I would also replace length:1 with length:sizeof(s) I think ints are 4 bytes, right?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the CoreFoundation [byte swapping](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Tasks/ByteSwapping.html) routines to convert the endianess of primitive types. If you have an `int`, you can use `CFSwapInt32HostToBig()` to swap the 32-bit integer to big-endian byte order before sending to your Java server.

Wouldn't it be better, ultimately, to use some standard format (e.g. JSON, XML, etc.) over the wire, letting the serialization and deserialization libraries handle endian issues, rather than re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: Hi, well I thought that would be the case.  I'm using Google Protocol Buffers and there I think there might be an issue there, but I'm not entirely sure how to verify it :(