# I am trying to convert Java byte[] to Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to convert this objective-c code. I want to create the same value as Java.

```
long value = 165500000;
for (int i = 8; i-- > 0; value >>= 8) {
    data[i] = (byte) value;
}
```

The code below is the code I converted to Objective-c. But the data is different from Java.
How do I get the same data as Java?

```
long time = 165500000;
char cData[8];
for (int i = 8; i-- > 0; time >>= 8) {
    cData[i] = (char)time;
}
```

Comment: You should look at big/little endian e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295354/objective-c-java-endian

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your two pieces of code do exactly the same thing and produce the same results when embedded in suitable code to make them complete programs. You need to edit your question to provide extra information to help people help you. The Java fragment doesn't define `data`, you don't say how you know the values are different (debugger, output statements?), you don't say what you expect the values to be, etc. Add this information and someone will undoubtedly help you. HTH